# Birds, an animal and a creature in the Kingdom

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Three colorful birds, one tropical

From African lands a wild animal

A made-up creature, beautiful, magical

Keeping order in the streets, we are essential

Who are we?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is:

> **PEDESTRIAN CROSSINGS** named after living (or in one case, mythical) creatures! These are most common in the UK and other nations whose road systems are based on the UK model (this explains the use of 'Kingdom' in the title).

Specifically...

*Three colorful birds, one tropical*

> A **pelican**, **puffin** and **toucan** (the 'tropical one' here).

*From African lands a wild animal*

> A **zebra**.

*A made-up creature, beautiful, magical*

> **[Pegasus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pegasus)** (the mythical, winged horse).

The differences between the different types are best explained as follows:

> A [pelican crossing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pelican_crossing) can be activated by pedestrians using a push-button. The pedestrian 'walk/don't walk' signal (taking the form of a green man and a red man, respectively) is positioned on the other side of the road to the push-button.
>
>  A [puffin crossing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puffin_crossing) is similar but has its pedestrian signals on the same post as the push-button.
>
>  A [toucan crossing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toucan_crossing) also allows bikes to be ridden across (with a specific bike symbol on the signal).
>
>  A [zebra crossing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_crossing) requires drivers to notice pedestrians and give way without a light signal (just a  flashing beacon, and black-and-white stripes on the road, hence the name).
>
>  Meanwhile, a [Pegasus crossing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pegasus_crossing) has its own special signal for horse riders!

Comment: Funnily enough, I thought of lion and unicorn which I think gave me the right "Kingdom" for the wrong reasons. +1

Comment: Gurl ner xvaq bs havdhr gb gur Havgrq "Xvatqbz" nerag gurl?

Comment: @DrD Modified to mention explicitly. Also revamped the links I originally provided to give greater detail. I've used this exact set of creatures when setting quiz questions before :)

Comment: Fvapr Crtnfhf vf abg n "yvivat" perngher lbh zvtug jnag gb zbqvsl lbhe svefg fgngrzrag va gur nafjre @Stiv

Comment: @DrD True. Modified accordingly!

Comment: Paying heed to Royal Navy traditions (probably), these animals come in some [slightly questionable flavours](https://i.imgur.com/zgetfyk.png) too.